# XSLT print attribute names using for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XML and XSLT. I'm trying to print all the variables under the  element using for-each but only 1  appears. How can I print all the  using for-each?

XSL:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:for-each select="/PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract">
   <h4>Abstract:</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="AbstractText"/></li>
   </ul>
   <h4>Copy Right Information</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="CopyrightInformation"/></li>
   </ul>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="article11.xsl"?>
<PubmedArticle>
  <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="In-Data-Review">
    <Article PubModel="Print-Electronic">
      <Abstract>
        <AbstractText Label="BACKGROUND" NlmCategory="BACKGROUND">Pituitary apoplexy is a rare clinical emergency which results from hemorrhage or infarction in the pituitary gland.</AbstractText>
        <AbstractText Label="PATIENT" NlmCategory="METHODS">We present a 14-year-old girl with pituitary apoplexy and review the literature.</AbstractText>
        <AbstractText Label="CONCLUSIONS" NlmCategory="CONCLUSIONS">Although pituitary apoplexy is rare in pediatric patients, prompt evaluation including detailed ophthalmic examination, biochemical evaluation, endocrine workup, and image study are very important.</AbstractText>
        <CopyrightInformation>Copyright c 2014 Elsevier Inc. All rights reserved.</CopyrightInformation>
      </Abstract>
    </Article>
  </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<h4>Abstract:</h4>
<ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="AbstractText"/></li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<h4>Abstract:</h4>
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="AbstractText">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Comment: @JoelLamsen Will this also apply if I print the attribute name of <AbstractText>?

Comment: if you want to print the attributes, use `<xsl:value-of select="@Label"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="@NlmCategory"/>`